# GROUP BY according to different conditions for each column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the table "Tcustomer":

```
+--------------+----------+---------+------------------+---------------+
| CustomerName | Product  | Country | Submitted_apps   | Finished_apps |
+--------------+----------+---------+------------------+---------------+
| Customer 1   | book1    | CZ      | 2020-11-06       | 2020-11-06    |
| Customer 2   | book1    | SK      | 2020-11-06       | 2020-11-07    |
| Customer 3   | book2    | CZ      | 2020-11-06       |     null      |
+--------------+----------+---------+------------------+---------------+
```

Now, I need to have one output that will say to me, how many submitted_apps was in each day, how many finished_apps was in each day per the product and the Country.

So in the output, something like this:

```
+----------+---------+----------+------------------+---------------+
| Product  | Country | Date     | Submitted_apps   | Finished_apps |
+----------+---------+----------+------------------+---------------+
| book1    | CZ      |2020-11-06| 1                | 1             |
| book2    | CZ      |2020-11-06| 1                | 0             |
| book1    | SK      |2020-11-06| 1                | 0             |
| book1    | SK      |2020-11-07| 0                | 1             |
+----------+---------+----------+------------------+---------------+
```

I did this, but it summarize only the date "submitted_apps". If I add also "finished_apps" to the GROUP BY statement, I have a lot of rows with nulls there.

My SQL code is this:

```
SELECT 
     COUNT (Submitted_apps) AS number_submitted_per_day,
     COUNT (Finished_apps) AS number_finished_per_day,
     Submitted_apps AS date

WHERE Submitted_apps > 2020-01-01
GROUP BY product, country, submitted_apps
```

But this SQL query tells me now, how many submitted and finished applications for the books was only for the date mentioned in "submitted_apps". But I need number of Finished_apps to the date "Finished_apps" and number of Submitted_apps" to the date "Submitted_apps".

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot the data using union all and then aggregate:

```
select Product, Country, date, sum(submitted) as num_submitted,
       sum(finished) as num_finished
from ((select Product, Country, Submitted_apps as date, 1 as submitted, 0 as finished
       from Tcustomer
      ) union all
      (select Product, Country, finished_apps as date, 0 as submitted, 1 as finished
       from Tcustomer
      ) 
     ) c
group by Product, Country, date;
```